# What does a python class name as a single line statement do

Tags: python

Can somebody explain the 2nd line (`unicode` is a class defined in the code)?

```
try:
    unicode
    _unicode = True
except NameError:
    _unicode = False
```

Comment: `unicode` is not a class defined in the code. It is a Python 2 built-in type.

Comment: You could also access `globals()` or `builtins` to check if there is a `unicode`

Comment: i have this class in my code. class unicode(basestring):

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: then the test is redundant, as the `basestring` name lookup will raise `NameError` in Python 3. In Python 2, that line is going to mask the built-in type, also an issue. Is this code public somewhere for us to have a look at?

Comment: Dont know if its public. I'm a fresher python developer and I'm trying to understand code from the project on which I'm going to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2 defines a [`unicode` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode). Python 3 does not ([`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) has taken this role). Trying to use the name `unicode` in Python 3 will thus raise a [`NameError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError).

In other words, using the type name on a line does nothing by itself other than trigger a name lookup. If that name lookup fails, you know that the type is not available:

```
$ python2.7 -c 'unicode'
$ python3.5 -c 'unicode'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

Comment: I have this class in my code. "class unicode(basestring):" Can you elaborate more on your second paragraph. What does name lookup means?

Comment: All variable names are stored in a namespace. Each time you try to use a name, it needs to be looked up in the namespace to get the associated value. `foo = 42` creates a name in the namespace. `if foo: print 'hello'` would be a name lookup, retrieving the `42` integer.

Comment: If you removed `foo = 42` from your program, `if foo:` would fail as the name `foo` was never defined. You'd get a `NameError` exception.

Comment: Code that uses `class unicode(basestring):` sounds *broken*. Without more details on that code I cannot begin to say anything more elaborate than that. Ask a separate question with enough context for us to see what is going on in that code.

Comment: Its a big class. The name lookup explanation helped. I could not understand what kind of statement it was. Thanks.